# Recursively call Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I've a method which makes post calls and on success it resolves a promise, but if the post calls fail for some reason I want to implement recursive logic to call the method that resolves the promise. How can I implement this to effectively handle the promises. Below is the code that i'm trying. Right now when the service call fails it is retrying but i'm getting unhandled rejection error and it is retrying again on it's own and then it is rejecting.

```
dummyService.getAction = (requestData) => {

    var options = {
        url: config.url,
        json: true,
        body: requestData,
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'x-request-id': 'IntegrationTesting'
        }
    }

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     request(options, function (error, response, body) {

            const success = new RegExp('^2\\d{2}$');
            const failure = new RegExp('^4\\d{2}$');

            if (error) {                
                reject(response);
            }
            else if (failure.test(response.statusCode) || recursive > 5) {                
                reject(response);
            }
            else if (success.test(response.statusCode) && body) {                
                resolve(body);
            }
            else {                
                recursive++;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    dummyService.getAction(requestData)
                }, 500);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: I finally found the solution for my problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173548/nodejs-http-retry-on-timeout-or-error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the promise returned by `dummyService.getAction` when you're retrying is basically ignored. Try this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    dummyService.getAction(requestData).then(resolve, reject);
}, 500);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm not understanding how to handle it, the solution you provided here didn't work unfortunately :(